# Xcode 7 iOS 9 getting this warning Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting this warning:

> Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
>
> NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:nil] dataTaskWithURL:nil];

Here is the full method:

```
+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:nil] dataTaskWithURL:nil];
        Class taskClass = [dataTask superclass];
        af_addMethod(taskClass, @selector(af_resume),  class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(af_resume)));
        af_addMethod(taskClass, @selector(af_suspend), class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(af_suspend)));
        af_swizzleSelector(taskClass, @selector(resume), @selector(af_resume));
        af_swizzleSelector(taskClass, @selector(suspend), @selector(af_suspend));
    });
}
```

How do I fix this? I am trying to clean up all my warnings.

Comment: The warning is pretty self-explanatory - you need to pass in an `NSURLSessionConfiguration` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot perform a task without any URL. The URL should not be nil. You should provide NSURL to performa task.

Also, you should not give nil to the configuration.

You should go either

```
         [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
```

Returns a newly created default session configuration object.

or

```
         [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
```

Returns a session configuration that uses no persistent storage for caches, cookies, or credentials.

So you should try:

```
   NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]] dataTaskWithURL:@"your NSURL"];
```

Note: Consider @"your NSURL" as NSURL but not as NSString

Comment: so change that line NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:nil] dataTaskWithURL:nil];
 to NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =  [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];

Comment: I added an NSURL and I still getting the warning with sessionWithConfiguration